# How do you pull data within a Date Range within an SSIS Script

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I'm using SSIS to connect to a SQL Server Database and pull a table into another SQL Server Database. Using Visual Studio 2013 to manage the SSIS scripts.

One of the tables I need to pull is huge so I'd like to just pull data that is greater than a date Range. ie: Data from Jan 1 2016 and newer.
How do i do this via SSIS? I feel like there should be somewhere to add a 'Where' clause or the equivelent to that.

Is it easier to link the two databases, although for security reasons I'm not sure if that is an option.

Any insight would be great. 
Thanks!

Comment: How are you *pulling the table into another SQL Server Database*? It should be as easy as adding the where clause to what ever statement you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a script.  Create a data flow and set up your source via sql command or create a stored procedure to handle your filtering.  Here is an example using a sql command

[image]

Then create a destination and map the source columns to your destination.

Another option is to set the data access mode to a variable.  With this you can build the sql query via variables and make the date filter dynamic with a variable expressions.

I typically used stored procedures and pass in parameters for filtering but if you are just starting with ssis I would try the other two options first.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

- Use a Data Flow Task
- Configure the Source as OLE DB Source to data Access mode as SQL Command or SQL Command from variable (you can parametrize both)
- Add an OLE DB destination, configure Data access mode to Table or
  view - Fast load and Rows per batch and Maximum insert commit size to
  100000 (you need test to fits to your need)

Comment: To parameterize the SQL use the wildcard "?" and click on parameters button